# Button to stop subs with OnTime Macro doesn't stop

Tags: excel, vba, scheduled-tasks, rtd, ontime

I have a button assigned to the StopRecordingData sub to cancel both subs and it doesn't. The schedule False doesn't seem to cancel the scheduled subs in que.

```
Dim NextTime As Double

Sub RecordData()
    Dim Interval As Double
    Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range

    Application.StatusBar = "Recording Started"
    Set Capture = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C5:K5") 'Capture this row 
    of data
    With Worksheets("Journal") 'Record the data on this worksheet
    Set cel = .Range("A2") 'First timestamp goes here
    Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    cel.Value = Now
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Capture.Cells.Count).Value = Capture.Value
    End With
    NextTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "CloseWB"
End Sub

Sub CloseWB()
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData"
    ThisWorkbook.Close True
End Sub

Sub StopRecordingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Recording Stopped"
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData", False
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "CloseWB", False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either

- use 2 commas in the end or
- full method definition of OnTime method

as the syntax of [OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) method has 4 arguments and last 2 are optional.

> Application.OnTime EarliestTime, Procedure, [*LatestTime*],
>   [*Schedule*]

Also, for time related variables, prefer DATE over DOUBLE. Hence use this at the top.

```
Dim NextTime as Date
```

---

```
Sub StopRecordingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Recording Stopped"
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "RecordData",, False
    Application.OnTime NextTime, "CloseWB",, False
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub StopRecordingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Recording Stopped"
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTime, Procedure:="RecordData", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextTime, Procedure:="CloseWB", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Both give the run-time error 1004 of method of "on-time object" app failed. Not sure how to debug.   :/

Comment: It means that the either schedule do not exist and have been deleted before execution of these lines.

Comment: Change the data type of NextTime variable from DOUBLE to DATE